# How to solve joint bending with a mesh structure

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

How to solve joint bending with mesh structure

Hello, I want to make a stickman.

I have no knowledge of rigging and don't want perfection, so this time I used an add-on called Auto Rig Pro for rigging.

However, as shown in the attached image, my arms worked, but my legs did not bend well.
(I used the same object for my arms and legs)

It's difficult to touch the rig with Auto Rig Pro, so I'd like to change the mesh structure to solve this problem.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to change the mesh structure so that my legs bend well.

Blender 2.92
Windows 10[image]

Comment: if you want a step by step explanation, please provide your blend file. Then i can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need more geometry. Just insert more loopcuts and the deformation will be smoother.

e.g. left a cube without loopcuts and an armature.

right a cube with loopcuts and an armature.

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Ohh that's really simple!
And thank you for the verification image!

Comment: You are welcome. Would be nice if you can check that checkmate left to my answer so others know this answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry! Your answer save my life !! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you! Now I am a life safer! There should be a badge for this here!!! ‼️

Comment: I think so too, Mr. life safer! lol